# Perl Multithreading - worker threads stops working

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have the following perl code which makes asynchronous calls to two external bioinformatics programs. First, it runs a blastJob, and then it takes the results from that and runs an exonerateJob. I've adapted this code from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38253862/5597209) about moving my code to a multi-threaded approach.

The problem is frustrating because it only happens after several hours of running. I will leave the program to run overnight and find in the morning that the exonerateJobs are no longer running, but new blastJobs are still cranking through. There are no reported errors or anything. Another tidbit of information is that I've gone back and tested the input queries where the logs show that the exonerateJobs stopped working. The program completes just fine if I run a small number of queries through it, even if they're the queries that seemed to have caused problems previously. Since I'm not too familiar with the rules of multithreading, I'd like to know if there's a problem with my approach, or if it's potentially a problem with the external programs that are called. Here's the bit of code:

```
#Asynchronous calls to blast and exonerate
{
   my $blast_request_queue = Thread::Queue->new();
   my $exonerate_request_queue = Thread::Queue->new();

   my @blast_threads;
   for (1..NUM_BLAST_WORKERS) {
      push @blast_threads, async {
         while (my $q = $blast_request_queue->dequeue()) {
            my @results = blastJob($q, $blastopts_ref);
            foreach (@results) {
               my @args = ($q, $_);
               $exonerate_request_queue->enqueue(\@args);
            }
         }

         $exonerate_request_queue->end(); # I've tried with and without this line, the result seems to be the same
      };
   }

   my @exonerate_threads;
   for (1..NUM_EXONERATE_WORKERS) {
      push @exonerate_threads, async {
         while (my $args_ref = $exonerate_request_queue->dequeue()) {
            my ($queryFile, $targetName) = @$args_ref; #De-reference args
            my $regex = qr/\Q$targetName\E/;
            #Check for target file
            my ($file_match) = grep { $_ =~ $regex } keys %targets;
            if ($file_match) {
                my $targetFile = $options{'t'} . $file_match;
                my $result = exonerateJob($queryFile, $targetFile, $exonopts_ref);
                #Print result to file after job is finished
                my ($Qname, $Qpath, $Qsuffix) = fileparse($queryFile);
                my $outFN = $Qname . ".exonerate_out";
                open(OUTFH, ">>$outFN") or print STDERR "Can't open $outFN: $!";
                print OUTFH $result;
            } else {
                print STDERR "Target file not found: $targetName. Can't run exonerate";
            }
         }
      };
   }

    foreach (@queries) {
        #Concatenate query path with name
        my $queryFile = $options{'q'} . $_;
        $blast_request_queue->enqueue($queryFile);
    }
    #my $queryFile = $options{'q'} . $queries[3];
    #$blast_request_queue->enqueue($queryFile);

   $blast_request_queue->end();    
   $_->join() for @blast_threads;
   $exonerate_request_queue->end();
   $_->join() for @exonerate_threads;
}

#I'm using IPC::Run to launch the programs.
#There is some error handling which I believe should catch any probs
sub blastJob {
    my ($query, $blastopts_ref) = @_;
    #De-reference blast options
    my @blastCmd = @$blastopts_ref;
    my ($blastOut, $err); #for blast output
    #Add query information after first blast option
    splice(@blastCmd, 1, 0, ("-query", $query));
    my ($Qname, $Qpath, $Qsuffix) = fileparse($query);
    print "Running $blastCmd[0]: query $Qname...\n";
    run \@blastCmd, \undef, \$blastOut, \$err;
    if ($err) {
        print "Error in BLAST query $Qname. $err\n";
    }
    my @results = split("\n", $blastOut);
    return uniq(@results);
}

sub exonerateJob {
    my ($query, $target, $exonopts_ref) = @_;
    #De-reference exonerate options
    my @exonCmd = @$exonopts_ref;
    my ($exonOut, $err); #for exonerate output
    #Add program, query, and target information to exonerate options
    unshift (@exonCmd, ("exonerate", "-q", $query, "-t", $target));
    my ($Qname, $Qpath, $Qsuffix) = fileparse($query);
    my ($Tname, $Tpath, $Tsuffix) = fileparse($target);
    eval {
        print "Running exonerate: query $Qname, target $Tname...\n";
        run \@exonCmd, \undef, \$exonOut, \$err, timeout(240);
        if ($err) {
            print STDERR "Error in exonerate query $Qname, target $Tname. $err\n";
        }
    };
    if ($@ =~ /timeout/) {
        print STDERR "Error: timeout in exonerate query $Qname, target $Tname\n";
    }

    return $exonOut;
}
```

Comment: Tip: `warn("x\n")` is not only shorter than `print(STDERR "x\n")`, is also causes `$SIG{__WARN__}` to be called if set. This is a better approach.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You could print a message after the dequeue loops to see if the thread exited because the dequeue returned false, or for some other reason.

Comment: I don't know much about Thread::Queue, but you might need to flush your stderr buffer. If it fills up from some sort of error from your data, it could be a problem.  I don't know if IO::Select is thread safe, but I use it to cycle through the output handles I get back from IO::Pipe::Producer. I know that with child processes, if you don't do that, you can run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

Without your source information, I can't test it - but my money would be on the first time you:

```
$exonerate_request_queue->end();
```

In that async block.

Because I think it's quite possible there, that *as soon* as you close the

```
$blast_request_queue->end();
```

Then a thread will exit soon after, close the 'output' queue, and in doing so - mean you lose anything that was pending, because the queue is closed.

Comment: `$exonerate_request_queue->end();` is indeed being called too soon, although it's not necessarilly called as soon as `$blast_request_queue->end();` is called. The code on which the OP based his did not suffer from this problem. That said, I'm not convinced this is the problem the OP is asking about.

Comment: I should have noted that I tried removing that line as well. I'll edit my Q to reflect this. The result was the same, frustratingly.

Answer (score 1):

You've gone to a lot of trouble to avoid `die`, when you should simply have added an `eval BLOCK` around the worker code.

Change

```
my $result = job1($job);
$job2_request_queue->enqueue($result);
```

to

```
my $result = eval { job1($job) };
if ($@) {
   warn("Job failed: $@");
} else {
   $job2_request_queue->enqueue($result);
}
```

This is far more reliable. For example, `run` can throw an exception which will kill your child.

---

Also, as Sobrique mentioned, the topmost instance of `$exonerate_request_queue->end();` should not been added. That prevents further work from being added to the queue (and signals the exonerate workers to exit once all the work currently in the queue has been performed). That should only be done after every blast worker has exited, but this addition causes this to be done as soon as the first blast worker exits.

Comment: Thanks Ikegami, I will try this approach as well as delete that line. To clarify, would you also advise changing the way that I handle errors within the subroutine, having them die rather than print to STDERR?

Comment: You mean how you print on `open` failure, but then try to use the handle anyway? Yeah, that needs to be changed.

Comment: Wow, yeah I agree that's pretty egregious. I definitely avoided `die`, mostly out of ignorance. I think I see how it will come together now.